# Authentication for scrapyRT

Tags: rest, authentication, scrapy

I like to use scrapyRT to connect all my scraper spiders to the Angular front-end.
The documentation recommends to run in it in production as follows:

```
docker run -p 9080:9080 -tid -v /home/user/quotesbot:/scrapyrt/project scrapinghub/scrapyrt
```

This will expose port 9080 to the outside world.
I'm concerned about the safety of this.

How can I properly secure this to avoid bots visiting the end points?

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing inside of scrapyRT itself. It's up to your server to you to secure your api. Firewall whitelist is proabably the most obvious and easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Scrapyrt is running on the same machine as your frontend, you could make Scrapyrt listen only on localhost:

```
docker run -p 9080:9080 -tid -v /home/user/quotesbot:/scrapyrt/project scrapinghub/scrapyrt -i 127.0.0.1
```

That way it will be accessible only from that machine (e.g. from the frontend application).

Otherwise use firewall to allow communication from your frontend machine only.

Comment: I did seen that option, but does it also hide the port to the outside world? I will test it as soon as I'm at work

Comment: @user3411864 Yes, it does. Check it out with `nmap` or try to `telnet` to that port from outside.